# SwiftUI Line/Slide Compass View Implementation

Tags: ios, swiftui

[image: Line Compass]

I am trying to implement the above type of compass in SwiftUI. My initial thought was to use a `ScrollView` and a `ScrollViewReader` but pretty quickly ran into the issue of going from 360 degrees to 1 degree or the opposite. I then thought about using a `LazyHStack` but that runs into similar issues.

Any thoughts on other approaches or how to make it work with my current approach would be awesome. The compass will have to seamlessly wrap around the values even if the user keeps just spinning in a circle either direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't go from 360 to 1 -- go to 361.

Comment: “My initial thought was to use a `ScrollView` and a `ScrollViewReader`”—should the compass view respond to drag and swipe gestures by scrolling?

Comment: I implemented something like this for a previous app. No scrollview, I believe I had just an hstack with a copy of the range before and after the centre one. Offset depending on bearing, if the offset moves outside the centre range to one of the adjacent ones, rearrange so the current one becomes a new centre range (despite the reshuffle, the effect was surprisingly seemless).  I'll look for the code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, It doesn't need to respond to user touch, @Cenk Bilgen, Thant would be awesome!

Comment: Made a package here: https://github.com/cenkbilgen/SwiftUICompass.git. It's not configurable at all, but look at the source for implementation ideas.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely take a look